# Value of type String cannot be converted into 1 dimensional array of String

Tags: arrays, vb.net

This is how I have declared my code:

```
Dim startline As String
Dim curserline As String
Dim curserpos As Integer
Dim x As Integer
Dim back As Boolean = False
Dim word() As String
Dim word1() As String

Dim AutoComplete As New List(Of String)


"This is part of my code but am not going to share all of it. I assume your getting."

 word1 = sr.ReadLine.Split("|"c)

 word = word1

 AutoComplete.Add(word(0) & word(1))


"For starters, I am getting this error here:"

Value of type String cannot be converted into 1 dimensional array of String

"From here:"


 word = Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, curserpos + 1, RichTextBox1.SelectionStart - curserpos)


"And here:"


 If auto.StartsWith(word) = True And word <> "" And word <> " " Then


"From this code here:"



Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged



    Try

        ListView1.Visible = False
        ListView1.Items.Clear()



        startline = RichTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(RichTextBox1.SelectionStart)
        curserline = RichTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(RichTextBox1.SelectionStart)
        curserpos = RichTextBox1.SelectionStart



        While Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, curserpos, 1) <> vbTab And Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, curserpos, 1) <> " " And Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, curserpos, 1) <> "." And Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, curserpos, 1) <> "=" And Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, curserpos, 1) <> "(" And Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, curserpos, 1) <> ")" And Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, curserpos, 1) <> "," And Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, curserpos, 1) <> "&" And Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, curserpos, 1) <> "{" And Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, curserpos, 1) <> "}" And Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, curserpos, 1) <> """" And Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, curserpos, 1) <> "<" And Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, curserpos, 1) <> ">" And Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, curserpos, 1) <> "!" And curserline = startline



            curserpos -= 1
            curserline = RichTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(curserpos)
        End While


        If curserline = startline Then
            word = Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, curserpos + 1, RichTextBox1.SelectionStart - curserpos)
        Else
            word = Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, curserpos + 2, RichTextBox1.SelectionStart - curserpos - 1)
        End If
```

Please help guys! This is a VB.NET question where am trying to build an Autocompletion. But the error displayed in the topic is making my life a living hell. Please help Guys!

The code I have just added:

```
   For Each auto As String In AutoComplete

            If auto.StartsWith(word) = True And word <> "" And word <> " " Then
```

Here is the sr. part please:

```
    Try
        Dim output As String = "C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication3\WindowsApplication3\My Project\Grammarchecker1.txt"


        If File.Exists(output) Then
            Using sr As New StreamReader(output)
                While Not sr.EndOfStream
                    word1 = sr.ReadLine.Split("|"c)

                    word = word1

                    AutoComplete.Add(word(0).ToString & word(1).ToString)


                End While
            End Using
        End If
```

Comment: You see that great big long line? You can simplify it with `Dim specialCharacters As String = vbTab & " .=(),&{}""<>!"` (next line) `While curserline = startline AndAlso specialCharacters.IndexOf(Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, curserpos, 1)) = -1`.

Comment: Thanks, let me work on it I will get back to you.

Comment: Can you edit your question to give us three or four sample lines from the file you are reading in with `sr`?

Comment: I have updated the long line with your code. Any more help please!

Comment: How do you expect people to help you if you dont provide the whole code? - I spent several hours trying to sort out the same code in a post from you under another user name and you never once explained that the code you were sending me wasnt the whole code. Not professional man.

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mishap, I can recall I mentioned it, but it is just an adjustment of the code. I sent it long ago, you should have checked it first. I hope you found the update.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this line:

```
word = Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, curserpos + 1, RichTextBox1.SelectionStart - curserpos)
```

You have already declared `word` as an **array** of strings on this line:

```
Dim word() As String '<-- the word() with the parens means it's an array of strings, not a single String.
```

The `Mid` function returns a **single** string, not an array of strings.  You should assign it to another variable which you declare as type `String`:

```
Dim singleWord As String = Mid(RichTextBox1.Text, curserpos + 1, RichTextBox1.SelectionStart - curserpos)
```

Comment: Thanks for your hard work to know programming. But I think it will also bring all kinds of errors on the code I have just added

Comment: I don't know what you mean.  That seems like a different question.

Comment: No, I am just saying, the word "word" is used in many parts of the program. You should wait two minutes to see my adjustment.

Comment: Please help where you can. I see you have this Expertise.

Comment: I need someone to help me please. I am in a desperate position.

Comment: **RoryAP** You have given me a nice suggestion but what's its application on the whole code? **SingleWord** this String does not have a purpose.

Comment: It will render my code from the sections I've removed **word** to become unusable.

Answer (score 0):

The list of strings is an array. I think that if you were to add the list of string like

```
  AutoComplete.Add(word(0).toString & word(1).toString )
```

you can then parse your array by

```
    Dim Starts_with As String = "0"
    For Each word In AutoComplete
        If word.StartsWith("D") Then
            Starts_with = word
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: It is saying word is used in an enclosed scope here:   AutoComplete.Add(word(0).toString & word(1).toString )

Comment: @codeMonger123 You should change the control variable name to something other than `word` because it is used elsewhere.

Comment: Agreed the variable names are throwing off how I am reading the code.

Comment: But your code is saying "word" is infered in an enclosed variable the one you have enclosed with .ToString?

Comment: OK, Andrew, I will do it.

Comment: **CodeMonger** You have commented on here: ** actually in your code isn't word1 = word?** What should it be? **Should I just stop the conversion?**

Comment: **Andrew Morton** Can you help me on the error being thrown? I hate to bother you, but when your lost, I know you will be gone forever. **Your the one who seems to know these kinds of problems**

Comment: **CodeMonger** Your code is giving me errors, what can I do?

Comment: Can one do this in VB:  Dim words2, word3 = words1.Split("|"), 

Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(words2)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be being overly frugal with your use of variables. You do not need to try to use as few as possible - it will only lead to problems.

For example, your code to read the data in could be more like

```
Dim inputFile As String = "C:\Users\Acer\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WindowsApplication3\WindowsApplication3\My Project\Grammarchecker1.txt"

If File.Exists(inputFile) Then
    Using sr As New StreamReader(inputFile)
        While Not sr.EndOfStream
            Dim wordParts = sr.ReadLine.Split("|"c)
            If wordParts.Count >= 2 Then
                AutoComplete.Add(wordParts(0) & wordParts(1))
            End If
        End While
    End Using
Else
    Throw New FileNotFoundException(String.Format("Input file {0} not found.", inputFile))
End If
```

Please note how I have named the input file as `inputFile` rather than `output`, and the parts of the word as `wordParts`. Disposing of variables which are no longer in use will be taken care of for you, if that is something you were concerned with. Also, I put in a check to make sure that there are at least two entries separated by "|" as otherwise `wordParts(1)` would not exist and so an exception would be thrown.

It could be that it does not matter if the file does not exist, in which case remove the `Throw New FileNotFoundException(String.Format("Input file {0} not found.", inputFile))` line.

Comment: What about here: **Dim wordParts = sr.ReadLine.Split("|"c)** I see how you have declared it nicely, but other parts have enclosed statements, and are asking for wordParts because they need it to perform other functions!

Comment: Declaration on top is the issue for other variables to use it not just for the Form Load event. The RichTextBox has some code that needs the WordParts.

Comment: @KelvinN. Populating the list `AutoComplete` should have nothing to do with the other parts of the code. I hope you did not rename your variables `word` and `word1`, because that would be wrong. The variable `wordParts` is  intended *only* for use in reading the file. Also, I very much suspect that you should not have declared `word` and `word1` as arrays.

Comment: I have removed them and your code is working **One Hundred Percent thank you!** You are great, the great shepherd**

Comment: I forgot to mention one thing that I am using a ListView, which seems to populate on one side, it should be populating on other column as well. Can you help with this by revisiting your code?

Comment: Thanks for all your help, but I will ask one question just this once more!. I have found that the delimited text is all going to one column and not the second column also. Could this be the problem: **ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItem(auto))**

Comment: Can you do this in VB : **Dim words2, word3 = words1.Split("|")**

Comment: **Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(words2)**